# How can I make wp-json authentication work over https for development only?

Tags: rest-api

I set my WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE to 'local' so that I could create an application password, but I cannot use this password to authenticate against the api. I cannot figure out whether it's possible, and if so, how to allow HTTP authentication without SSL.

I get the following error when I use http, but not when I use https (even though I set my WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE to local)

```
{
    "code": "rest_user_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Our production system is setup with https, but I cannot use https for development without a great deal of hassle.

Comment: are you using basic auth to try and connect locally? If so then HTTPS is non-negotiable and was deliberatley required by core for security reasons, but it's also not as difficult to set up as you might think, and a lot of local dev solutions automatically set up HTTPS and TLS certificates for you out of the box